# current lat long

Tags: php, geolocation

I want to display current location weather in my php website. Is it possible to fetch the current location(latitude,longitude) of a client computer.

Or what else we can do with weather ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using one of the newer browser versions that utilises the geolocation api you can use javascript to find the latitude and longitude as follows:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }, function() {
      alert("Geolocation Failed");
}
```

Comment: How can I use `latitude` and `longitude` out side the function. My need is to send these two variables in ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate the location based on IP address - if you are providing a weather service you can get the location to an appropriate level of accuracy using MaxMind.com - which provides a database & API to get location based on API.

Note - for users on a corporate network, the location will often be wrong. My corporate network places me in France, or Atlanta even though I'm in the UK. Off corporate network, it is unnervingly accurate.

If you need something more accurate (e.g. location based on WiFi or GPS), use the HTML5 Geo Location API - there are plenty of good answers on SO already on this topic (such as the one from Simnom).

Comment: Thank you kevin and simnom , I will do googling on the specified things..Thanks again